# Problem accessing samba share / permission denied

Tags: samba

i have installed samba and want to share a directory to everyone in my home network.
Everything works fine, if i share for example a directory inside my ubuntu user home directory:

```
home/drwade/temp/samba/anonymous
```

here i can access the share without any problem.
This is the section of my **/etc/samba/smb.conf:**

file:

```
[Anonymous]
    path = /home/drwade/temp/samba/anonymous
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes
    read only = no
    force user = nobody
    public = yes
```

I have now installed a 3 TB harddrive into my pc and formatted it with **ext3** and chowned the whole drive to my ubuntu user.
Then i have added it to the **/etc/samba/smb.conf:**

```
[Anonymous2]
    path = /media/drwade/DATA/samba/anonymous
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes
    read only = no
    force user = nobody
    public = yes
```

When i try to access the **Anonymous2** share on my Windows 7 machine, i get an **permission denied** error.

Could this be an mounting problem? have i forgot to configure something else?

Answer (score 4):

By design /media/$USER ( /media/drwade in this case ) will allow only one user to get past it and that is drwade. You are forcing the user to be "nobody". nobody != drwade so access is denied. Change your force user in the [Anonymous2] share definition to drwade:

```
force user = drwade
```